# wampserver port 80 - not working after windows update

Tags: apache, wamp, port

Things that are not installed/not using port 80: 
IIS,
Web Deploy 2.0 (Web Deployment Agent Service),
MS Sql Server Reporting service,
BranchCache ( Windows 8.1 ),
SQL Server VSS Writer

Error:
===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 80 =====

Test for TCP
Your port 80 is used by a processus with PID = 4
The processus of PID 4 is 'System' Session: Services
The service of PID 4 for 'System' is 'N/A'
*** ERROR *** This service IS NOT from Wampserver - Should be: 'wampapache64'

I really would like to use port 80 since my project is uncompleted.
(tried using another port - 81 - but i guess my wamp mapping isnt correct. for example: localhost/shop opened my project but localhost:81/shop did not)
Any ideas are greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: also marked Skype to use another port than 80. did restart after that

Comment: ntoskrnl is occupying port 80, no solution yet

Comment: holy shit - turns out that razer chroma (mouse) did use port 80 after update.

Comment: Man thank you so much. I spent almost two hours trying to find solution. What is that stupid service anyway, it seams Synapse works just fine even without SDK service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought I would mention this is as a formal answer since it is probably going to bite a lot of people and is difficult to diagnose -- it appears that a recent update to the 'Razer Chroma SDK Server' service ties up port 80 via Process ID 4 'System'.  This suddenly caused my XAMPP service to fail to start, and 'net stop http' command prompt command to fail.  Stopping this service frees up the port.

I was getting paranoid about perhaps malware being the culprit, so thank you so much to 'Scriptus' and whoever else contributed to solving this mystery!